# Erro recorrente com TFS

Tags: java, eclipse, team-foundation-server

Estou usando o Team Foundation Server pra um projeto do trabalho. Mas não consigo baixar os arquivos de código presentes no repositório.
Sempre que tento uma conexão, o Eclipse me devolve o erro como na imagem anexa.

Dados gerais do meu ambiente:
Conectamos em uma URL do VisualStudio, tipo ".visualstudio.com"
Minhas configurações de conexão/acesso estão corretas.
Reinstalar o eclipse/plugin não tem efeito, tudo continua na mesma.
Copiei da máquina de um colega de trabalho, porém lá funciona perfeitamente, e usamos as mesmas configurações em 3 máquinas; mas a minha entre todas é a não funciona.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: Anexo: erro que recebo sempre]

Comment: Você copiou os fontes da máquina do seu colega? Se sim, você não criou um workspace - que é o mapeamento que define onde os arquivos do servidor são salvos na sua máquina local. Isso envolve, por exemplo, o usuário logado para definir o "dono" do workspace. Se você já possui um workspace, sugiro apagá-lo e criar outro, lembrando sempre de fazer um backup de mudanças pendentes caso as tenha.

Comment: Vinicius, funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado!

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Citação
>   Você copiou os fontes da máquina do seu colega? Se sim, você não criou um workspace - que é o mapeamento que define onde os arquivos do servidor são salvos na sua máquina local. Isso envolve, por exemplo, o usuário logado para definir o "dono" do workspace. Se você já possui um workspace, sugiro apagá-lo e criar outro, lembrando sempre de fazer um backup de mudanças pendentes caso as tenha.

@viniciushana